# Spark DataFrame Add Column with Value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` with below data

```
scala> nonFinalExpDF.show
+---+----------+
| ID|      DATE|
+---+----------+
|  1|      null|
|  2|2016-10-25|
|  2|2016-10-26|
|  2|2016-09-28|
|  3|2016-11-10|
|  3|2016-10-12|
+---+----------+
```

From this `DataFrame` I want to get below `DataFrame`

```
+---+----------+----------+
| ID|      DATE| INDICATOR|
+---+----------+----------+
|  1|      null|         1|
|  2|2016-10-25|         0|
|  2|2016-10-26|         1|
|  2|2016-09-28|         0|
|  3|2016-11-10|         1|
|  3|2016-10-12|         0|
+---+----------+----------+
```

Logic -

1. For latest DATE(MAX Date) of an ID, Indicator value would be 1 and others
   are 0.
2. For null value of the account Indicator would be 1

Please suggest me a simple logic to do that.

Comment: Post your code, what you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
spark.sql("""
  SELECT id, date,
    CAST(LEAD(COALESCE(date, TO_DATE('1900-01-01')), 1)
    OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) IS NULL AS INT)
  FROM df""")
```

Comment: Its working. I have used "registerTempTable" instead of  createOrReplaceTempView.